# Lightbox style image browser for Windows

Tags: windows, image-viewer

Picassa used to have that cool feature, but it's gone.

I simply want to browse my pictures with lightbox effect, using mousewheel to zoom in/out and arrows to switch between photos.

Is it something out there ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe [ACDSee](https://www.acdsee.com/en/products/acdsee-free/)

Answer (score 1):

[ImageGlass](https://imageglass.org/) has this feature.

Steps to reproduce this effect:

1. Go into a folder with photos
2. Open a photo with ImageGlass
3. Press Alt+Enter or the relevant button to go full screen
4. Use Wheel Up + Down to zoom in/out
5. Use arrows (left/right) to move between images

Also ImageGlass is totally free for any purpose use.
Its source code was released under the terms of the GNU General Public License v3.0

ImageGlass has a lot of features some of them are:

Image viewing

```
Supports over 70+ common image formats, including PNG, GIF, SVG*, WEBP*, HEIC, RAW,...
Losslessly rotate / save the viewing image.
Ability of opening image from clipboard directly.
Rapidly switch between images.
Drag-n-Drop viewing image supported.
Real-time update the viewing image.
Works great with GIF format: extract image frames, play/pause animation.
5 zoom modes: Auto Zoom, Scale to Width, Scale to Height, Zoom to Fit, Lock Zoom Ratio.
Various image navigation options: shortcuts, mousewheel
Horizontal / Vertical image scrolling.
Fast thumbnail preview.
Thumbnail images can be shown in the current viewing folder.
Color Picker tool allows user to pick and convert color to 4 formats: RGBA, HEXA, CMYK, HSLA.
Slideshow viewing functionality.
Conversion can be made in up to 10 different formats.
Possibility of sharing the image being viewed to Facebook.
Quick shortcuts supported.
Clean nice modern minimal UI; posibility of hide/show toolbar.
Different theme packs available to change the look of the interface.
Multilanguage support, which makes the user able to create its own packs.
```

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHhz-Ew8M7A

Comment: Not entirely what I was looking for, but still really cool image browser. Lightbox is not there but if you know how to add it, please share